# XML, ElementTree - Extract attributes and match them to on ID

Tags: python, xml, pycharm, elementtree

Hello everyone and greetings from germany!

I'm rather new to python and i have a question concerning XML-files.
My data looks something like this (there are a lot of  elements in this file, each with a unique way-id):

```
    <way id="4260867" visible="true" version="12" changeset="71461925" timestamp="2019-06-        
      20T21:42:40Z" user="L___I" uid="7649834">
      <nd ref="25550395"/>
      <nd ref="25550396"/>
      <tag k="bicycle" v="no"/>
      <tag k="bridge" v="yes"/>
      <tag k="foot" v="no"/>
      <tag k="hazmat" v="designated"/>
      <tag k="highway" v="motorway_link"/>
      <tag k="maxspeed" v="none"/>
      <tag k="motorcar" v="yes"/>
      <tag k="oneway" v="yes"/>
      <tag k="placement" v="middle_of:1"/>
      <tag k="source:maxspeed" v="DE:motorway"/>
     </way>
     <way id="312407268" visible="true" version="9" changeset="116383142" 
      timestamp="2022-01-20T12:11:26Z" user="m_p_13" uid="2465271">
      <nd ref="7792523927"/>
      <nd ref="25393142"/>
      <nd ref="5583629192"/>
      <nd ref="25393143"/>
      <tag k="bdouble" v="yes"/>
      <tag k="bicycle" v="no"/>
      <tag k="foot" v="yes"/>
      <tag k="highway" v="secondary"/>
      <tag k="horse" v="yes"/>
      <tag k="lanes" v="2"/>
      <tag k="maxspeed" v="60"/>
      <tag k="motorcar" v="yes"/>
      <tag k="name" v="Messe-Allee"/>
      <tag k="name:etymology:wikidata" v="Q57305"/>
      <tag k="oneway" v="yes"/>
      <tag k="ref" v="K 6529"/>
      <tag k="shoulder" v="no"/>
      <tag k="surface" v="asphalt"/>
     </way>
     <way id="106141287" visible="true" version="3" changeset="101880267" timestamp="2021-03- 
      28T16:10:05Z" user="user_2954791" uid="2954791">
      <nd ref="913936737"/>
      <nd ref="1222080363"/>
      <tag k="bicycle" v="designated"/>
      <tag k="cycleway" v="crossing"/>
      <tag k="smoothness" v="intermediate"/>
      <tag k="surface" v="paving_stones"/>
      <tag k="traffic_sign" v="DE:241"/>
     </way>
```

What i want to do is extract every ID and match the attributes "nd ref" (node_ids, number differs from way_id to way_id) and (if  contains  the value "blub"

So in the end it should look something like this:

```
(id, node_ids, maxspeed)
(4260867, (25550395,25550396), None)
(106141287, (913936737, 1222080363), NaN)
```

I started to work with elementTree and was able to extract the IDs. I can also print out all attribs from  via

```
for way in root.findall('way'):
   for i in way.findall('tag'): print(i.attrib)
```

But I'm not able to get those values in the form that i want.

I hope i can get some help!
Also if someone has a better way to organize the data instead of tuple i would appreciate that!
I dont know if it is important or not but i work with Pycharm.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why is `maxspeed` in your expected output if its always `none`?

Comment: Its not always none. It represents the speed limit on a road. It can be any limit possible. I think that if its a sidewalk then maxspeed is not available or there is no speedlimit (maxspeed = None)

Comment: So i found a way to get all the "maxspeed"-values but i'm not sure if it is a good way to do it:
`for way in root.findall('way/tag'):  
pattern = r".+'v':\s'(.+[a-z]|.+|\d{1,})'}"  
value = str(way.attrib)   
if "maxspeed" in value:  
v =re.findall(pattern, value)  
print(v)`  
    
This gives me the following answer (just a few):
['50']
['60']
['60']
['25']
['60']
['none']

Now i need to match them to my way-ids.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add an example of a `<way>` element where `maxspeed` is not none?

Comment: Done! As you can see there are also more node-ids mentioned in this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are probably looking for something like the below. I chose to run it through pandas, just to demonstrate the structure, but obviously you can do something else if you so choose.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

ways = """[your xml above, wrapped in a root element]"""
doc = ET.fromstring(ways)
targets = doc.findall('.//way')
rows= []
cols = ["id", "node_ids", "maxspeed"]
for target in targets:
    id = target.attrib['id']
    nds = [nd.attrib['ref'] for nd in target.findall('.//nd') ]
    ms = target.find(".//tag[@k='maxspeed']").attrib['v'] if target.find(".//tag[@k='maxspeed']") is not None else None
    rows.append([id,nds,ms])
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
df
```

Output:

```
    id  node_ids    maxspeed
0   4260867     [25550395, 25550396]    none
1   312407268   [7792523927, 25393142, 5583629192, 25393143]    60
2   106141287   [913936737, 1222080363]     None
```

Note: this would be somewhat simpler if you use lxml instead of ElementTree.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! I had to modify it a bit because doc = ET.fromstring(ways) didn't work for me. I had to write doc = ET.fromstring(open("path to xml").read()) . But thank you!!